# std::transform with std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you use `std::transform` in conjunction with containers which hold objects of type `std::reference_wrapper`? when reading from `const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const float>>` and writing into an `std::vector<float>` everything works, but if I try to write into an `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>>` it doesn't compile giving the error

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:4214: error: use of deleted function >'std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = float]'
>    *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);

I think it is trying to replace the reference instead of changing the value of the referred value. Is there a way to use transform to achieve this or should I prefer writing my own function?

edit: added a example for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
std::vector<float> v(3, 1.0f);
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>> refVector;

refVector.reserve(v.size());
for(auto& elem : v)
{
refVector.push_back((std::reference_wrapper<float>)elem);
}

std::vector<float> v2(3, 2.0f);
std::vector<float> v3(3, 3.0f);
std::vector<float> v4(3);

for(auto& elem : v)
std::cout << elem << std::endl; // all 1s

std::transform(refVector.begin(), refVector.end(), v3.begin(), v4.begin(), std::plus<float>());

for(auto& elem : v4)
std::cout << elem << std::endl; // all 4s

std::transform(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v3.begin(), refVector.begin(), std::minus<float>()); // doesn't compile

for(auto& elem : v)
std::cout << elem << std::endl; // want all -1s

return 0;
}
```

Comment: A reference wrapper holds a pointer to an object. You can't form a pointer to the value `3.14`. So you can't put `3.14` directly into a reference wrapper, but you *can* put a reference to a variable there.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Probably OP wants to put the value 3.14 into the object that the wrapper holds reference to.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov that's what i meant

Comment: Can you show the code that "works" and the code that gives that error, rather than describing them?

Comment: Well, there is `get` member function for getting the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to overwrite existing `float`s that are referenced in your `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>>`, then you need something that will unwrap the `std::reference_wrapper<float>` into a `float &`. [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html) is such a thing, although it is easy to write your own iterator adapter if you can't add a boost dependancy.

An example usage:

```
std::vector<float> src1 = /* values */, src2 = /* other values */;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>> dest = /* references to somewhere */;

boost::indirect_iterator<std::reference_wrapper<float>, float> indirected(dest.begin());
std::transform(src1.begin(), src1.end(), src2.begin(), indirected, std::plus<float>());
```

A sketch implementation

```
struct indirect_iterator
{
    /* a bunch of typedefs go here */
    indirect_iterator& operator++() { ++inner; }
    float & operator*() { return inner->get(); }
    float * operator->() { return &inner->get(); }  
private:
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<float>>::iterator inner;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don"t have boost so i'll have to start writing my first iterator. any crucial advice you feel like giving?

Comment: I've added a sketch of the main operation. The basic gist is anywhere the iterator would serve up a value, it calls `std::reference_wrapper::get` on the value returned by `inner`, and elsewhere it just calls the operation on `inner`

Comment: I just found out boost is actually installed, I could get the sketch to work but wasn't able to do it with boost

Comment: I recommend just using an ordinary `for` loop. It is (1) shorter code, and (2) more clear.